# Smartphone Bookmark

Tags: javascript, android, html, iphone

I am working on smartphone site. Is there a way to set "Bookmark this site" button on both Android and iPhone site like old school website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't, and I hope nobody implements this, it is too obstrusive.

What some sites do, at last on iPhone, is to create a popup pointing to the bookmark button (see youtube mobile) asking if the user wants to bookmark it.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo. I had some trouble convincing my client but I did finally. Your answer was my big emotional support :)